# error 0xC00CE020: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema ,,, Required attribute 'ForegroundText' is missing

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

Launched a "blank Windows 10 Universal App" using "Visual Studio 2015 RC". I am not able to see the design view for MainPage.xaml. The designer shows the following Error:

> error 0xC00CE020: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 20, Column 8, Reason: Required
>   attribute 'ForegroundText' is missing

Tried including 'ForegroundText="dark"' attribute in Package.appxmanifest file but the attribute seems to be undeclared for VisualElements.

```
     <uap:VisualElements
          DisplayName="BackgroundSensorsCS"
          Square150x150Logo="Assets\squareTile-sdk.png"
          Square44x44Logo="Assets\SmallTile-sdk.png"
          Description="BackgroundSensorsCS"
          BackgroundColor="#00b2f0"
          **ForegroundText="dark"**>
            <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\Splash-sdk.png" />
            <uap:DefaultTile>
                <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
                    <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
                </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
            </uap:DefaultTile>
        </uap:VisualElements>
```

Comment: What build of Windows and what build of VS do you have?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by selecting Lock screen notifications item.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, today, Visual Studio 2022, this happened after adding Badge Logos to the Visual Assets in the App Manifest, for store distribution. Apparently, when you add badges it is assumed you are receiving notifications, and you are required to select "Lock screen notifications" in the "Application" tab in the package manifest editor. Once you select Lock screen notifications: Badge the error disappears. Or, remove the Badge Logos if you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after re-installing Visual Studio 2015 RC on Windows 10 Preview, Build 10074.

Comment: Anything can be resolved by re-installing anything, but that is no answer to a simple problem, and is a costly operation. See the answer below, about Badge Logos.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I started experiencing a similar issue while developing a UWP app. It said some 'Wide..' attribute was not defined in the DTD. So I went to the project's properties > Application and tried to open the package manifest. I then deleted the faulty attribute from the manifest xml, restarted VS and opened package manifest file again which opened this time fine.

So, something there seems to have fixed the issue. Also, I cleaned the deployment inside bin > Debug and re-deployed, which worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Explorer -> Package.appxmanifest -> right click -> View code ->
Find the tag: <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="### GUID ###"
-> Add property PhonePublisherId="### GUID ###"

I've added the same ID like my publisher ID

Good luck...